# python-polars: string columns to lists to integer columns

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to convert a TSV file in  [BED12 format](https://felixfan.github.io/bedtools/) to a polars data frame. I got two columns encoded as strings containing coma separated integers. My solution (simplified) involves going through structs:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "chrom": ["1", "1", "2", "X"],
        "blockSizes": ["10,29,", "20,22,", "30,25,", "40,23,"],
        "blockStarts": ["0,50,", "0,45,", "0,60,", "0,70,"]
    })

df.with_columns(col("blockSizes").str.split(by=",")
.list.slice(0, 2)
.list.to_struct()
).unnest("blockSizes").with_columns(
    [
        col("field_0").cast(pl.Int32).alias("blockSizes_0"),
        col("field_1").cast(pl.Int32).alias("blockSizes_1"),
    ]
).drop(["field_0", "field_1"])
```

Obviously I can just continue with doing the same with `blockStarts` column but I hope there is some simpler way to do it.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Do the number of items in `blockSizes` and `blockStarts` always match? (I assume it's not always `2`?) And you really want each one as its own column?

Comment: Yes, ```blockSizes``` must have the same number of items as ```blockStarts```. In a somehow special case the number of , ```blockSizes``` is 2, but the input file has an extra coma like this ```36,38,``` so I am slicing the first two in polars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current approach could be modified:

- [`.strip_chars()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.strip_chars.html#polars.Expr.str.strip_chars) to remove the trailing comma
- `.cast(pl.List(pl.Int32))` to cast everything at once
- pass a function to `.to_struct(fields=)` to rename the fields "dynamically"

```py
cols = "blockSizes", "blockStarts"

(df.with_columns(
    pl.col(col)
      .str.strip_chars(",")
      .str.split(",")
      .cast(pl.List(pl.Int32))
      .list.to_struct(
         n_field_strategy = "max_width", 
         fields = lambda idx, col=col: f"{col}_{idx}"
      )
    for col in cols
 )
 .unnest(cols)
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 5)
┌───────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────┐
│ chrom ┆ blockSizes_0 ┆ blockSizes_1 ┆ blockStarts_0 ┆ blockStarts_1 │
│ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---           ┆ ---           │
│ str   ┆ i32          ┆ i32          ┆ i32           ┆ i32           │
╞═══════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 10           ┆ 29           ┆ 0             ┆ 50            │
│ 1     ┆ 20           ┆ 22           ┆ 0             ┆ 45            │
│ 2     ┆ 30           ┆ 25           ┆ 0             ┆ 60            │
│ X     ┆ 40           ┆ 23           ┆ 0             ┆ 70            │
└───────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Perhaps creating a function would neaten things up.

```py
def csv_to_struct(col):
    expr = pl.col(col).str.strip_chars(",").str.split(",")
    expr = expr.cast(pl.List(pl.Int32))
    return expr.list.to_struct(
        n_field_strategy = "max_width", 
        fields = lambda idx: f"{col}_{idx}"
    )

cols = "blockSizes", "blockStarts"

df.with_columns(map(csv_to_struct, cols)).unnest(cols)
```

#### melt/pivot

Another way to approach it could be to use [`.melt()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt) + [`.pivot()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```py
cols = "blockSizes", "blockStarts"

(df.with_row_count()
   .with_columns(
      pl.col(cols).str.strip_chars(",").str.split(",").cast(pl.List(int))
   )
   .explode(cols)
   .melt(["row_nr", "chrom"], variable_name="name")
   .with_columns(
      pl.format("{}_{}", "name", pl.col("row_nr").cum_count().over("row_nr", "name"))
   )
   .pivot("value", ["row_nr", "chrom"], "name")
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 6)
┌────────┬───────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ chrom ┆ blockSizes_0 ┆ blockSizes_1 ┆ blockStarts_0 ┆ blockStarts_1 │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---           ┆ ---           │
│ u32    ┆ str   ┆ i64          ┆ i64          ┆ i64           ┆ i64           │
╞════════╪═══════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 1     ┆ 10           ┆ 29           ┆ 0             ┆ 50            │
│ 1      ┆ 1     ┆ 20           ┆ 22           ┆ 0             ┆ 45            │
│ 2      ┆ 2     ┆ 30           ┆ 25           ┆ 0             ┆ 60            │
│ 3      ┆ X     ┆ 40           ┆ 23           ┆ 0             ┆ 70            │
└────────┴───────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: Manty thanks! Works, just that the first block of code also needs the tuple``` cols = "blockSizes", "blockStarts"```.